# Text input box in SDL

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I would like to know if there is an equivalent in SDL to Javascript's `prompt()` function. In case you don't know Javascript, here is a screenshot of what Javascript `prompt()` does:

[image: textinputbox]

So what I want is a function for SDL which opens a dialog box like the one above and returns a string with what the user typed (or takes a pointer to a string in an argument and puts what the user typed in that string).

How can I do this in SDL?

Comment: SDL is not a GUI widget toolkit. It can handle drawing, overall keyboard/mouse input, timing, etc. But it does not provide any ready-made GUI controls or other elements. Use a GUI widget toolkit. Any good one "works with SDL" if you instruct it properly.

Comment: @underscore_d `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox()` is SDL2 and it does something similar. Why would there be a way to show a message box but not a text input box?

Comment: How would I know? I didn't write it. But opening a basic dialog box is a lot more generic across the various platforms supported by SDL - than it would be to create a window with a platform-dependent text input, platform-dependent buttons, etc and a platform-dependent mechanism for detecting actions and obtaining the entered value. Such are the province of GUI widget toolkits.

Comment: @underscore_d So do you mean that I would have to use QT or WxWidgets or something like that and make it work with SDL?

Comment: That's my suspicion. While you're evaluating toolkits, also look at GTK+/gtkmm/[insert other GTK+ binding here], a great cross-platform toolkit with many great features and various exciting development stuff going on (i.e. don't believe the internet fearmongering, and I have no affiliation, blah blah).

Comment: @underscore_d Thanks for the tip about using GTK+. I didn't know GTK+ before and I've just learned how to install and use it, and I find it much easier to install than QT or WxWidgets. But I have some problems trying to combine SDL windows and GTK+ windows in the same program. I asked a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794660/combining-sdl-windows-and-gtk-windows-in-the-same-program) about this problem.

Comment: Cool! I'll see you there :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for input widget.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>

int windowWidth = 240;
int windowHeight = 320;
SDL_Point mousePos;
SDL_Point realMousePos;
bool keys[SDL_NUM_SCANCODES];
bool buttons[SDL_BUTTON_X2 + 1];
SDL_Renderer* renderer;

int SDL_QueryTextureF(SDL_Texture* texture, Uint32* format, int* access, float* w, float* h)
{
    int wi, hi;
    int result = SDL_QueryTexture(texture, format, access, &wi, &hi);
    if (w) {
        *w = wi;
    }
    if (h) {
        *h = hi;
    }
    return result;
}

SDL_Texture* renderText(SDL_Texture* previousTexture, TTF_Font* font, SDL_Renderer* renderer, const std::string& text, SDL_Color color)
{
    if (previousTexture) {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(previousTexture);
    }
    SDL_Surface* surface;
    if (text.empty()) {
        surface = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font, " ", color);
    }
    else {
        surface = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font, text.c_str(), color);
    }
    if (surface) {
        SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        return texture;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

struct Text {
    std::string text;
    SDL_Surface* surface = 0;
    SDL_Texture* t = 0;
    SDL_FRect dstR{};
    bool autoAdjustW = false;
    bool autoAdjustH = false;
    float wMultiplier = 1;
    float hMultiplier = 1;

    ~Text()
    {
        if (surface) {
            SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        }
        if (t) {
            SDL_DestroyTexture(t);
        }
    }

    Text()
    {

    }

    Text(const Text& rightText)
    {
        text = rightText.text;
        if (surface) {
            SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        }
        if (t) {
            SDL_DestroyTexture(t);
        }
        if (rightText.surface) {
            surface = SDL_ConvertSurface(rightText.surface, rightText.surface->format, SDL_SWSURFACE);
        }
        if (rightText.t) {
            t = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
        }
        dstR = rightText.dstR;
        autoAdjustW = rightText.autoAdjustW;
        autoAdjustH = rightText.autoAdjustH;
        wMultiplier = rightText.wMultiplier;
        hMultiplier = rightText.hMultiplier;
    }

    Text& operator=(const Text& rightText)
    {
        text = rightText.text;
        if (surface) {
            SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        }
        if (t) {
            SDL_DestroyTexture(t);
        }
        if (rightText.surface) {
            surface = SDL_ConvertSurface(rightText.surface, rightText.surface->format, SDL_SWSURFACE);
        }
        if (rightText.t) {
            t = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
        }
        dstR = rightText.dstR;
        autoAdjustW = rightText.autoAdjustW;
        autoAdjustH = rightText.autoAdjustH;
        wMultiplier = rightText.wMultiplier;
        hMultiplier = rightText.hMultiplier;
        return *this;
    }

    void setText(SDL_Renderer* renderer, TTF_Font* font, std::string text, SDL_Color c = { 255,255,255 })
    {
        this->text = text;
#if 1 // NOTE: renderText
        if (surface) {
            SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        }
        if (t) {
            SDL_DestroyTexture(t);
        }
        if (text.empty()) {
            surface = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font, " ", c);
        }
        else {
            surface = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font, text.c_str(), c);
        }
        if (surface) {
            t = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
        }
#endif
        if (autoAdjustW) {
            SDL_QueryTextureF(t, 0, 0, &dstR.w, 0);
        }
        if (autoAdjustH) {
            SDL_QueryTextureF(t, 0, 0, 0, &dstR.h);
        }
        dstR.w *= wMultiplier;
        dstR.h *= hMultiplier;
    }

    void setText(SDL_Renderer* renderer, TTF_Font* font, int value, SDL_Color c = { 255,255,255 })
    {
        setText(renderer, font, std::to_string(value), c);
    }

    void draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
    {
        if (t) {
            SDL_RenderCopyF(renderer, t, 0, &dstR);
        }
    }
};

std::string ucs4ToUtf8(const std::u32string& in)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(in);
}

std::u32string utf8ToUcs4(const std::string& in)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv;
    return conv.from_bytes(in);
}

void utf8Insert(std::string& buffer, int index, std::string text)
{
    std::u32string u32Buffer = utf8ToUcs4(buffer);
    if (index > u32Buffer.size()) {
        index = u32Buffer.size();
    }
    u32Buffer.insert(index, utf8ToUcs4(text));
    buffer = ucs4ToUtf8(u32Buffer);
}

std::string utf8Substr(const std::string& str, unsigned int start, unsigned int leng)
{
    std::u32string s = utf8ToUcs4(str);
    return ucs4ToUtf8(s.substr(start, leng));
}

std::size_t utf8GetSize(std::string buffer)
{
    std::u32string str = utf8ToUcs4(buffer);
    return str.size();
}

void utf8Erase(std::string& buffer, int index)
{
    buffer = utf8Substr(buffer, 0, index) + utf8Substr(buffer, index + 1, std::string::npos);
}

struct Input {
    SDL_Rect r{};
    Text text;
    SDL_Rect cursorR{};
    int currentLetter = 0;
    std::u32string left;
    std::u32string right;
    bool isPassword = false;
    bool isSelected = false;

    void handleEvent(SDL_Event event, TTF_Font* font)
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            if (event.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_BACKSPACE) {
                if (currentLetter) {
                    utf8Erase(text.text, currentLetter - 1);
                    if (!right.empty()) {
                        std::u32string s = utf8ToUcs4(text.text);
                        s.push_back(right.front());
                        right.erase(0, 1);
                        text.text = ucs4ToUtf8(s);
                    }
                    else if (!left.empty()) {
                        std::u32string s = utf8ToUcs4(text.text);
                        s.insert(0, 1, left.back());
                        left.pop_back();
                        text.text = ucs4ToUtf8(s);
                    }
                    else {
                        --currentLetter;
                    }
                    text.setText(renderer, font, text.text, {});
                }
            }
            else if (event.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT) {
                if (currentLetter) {
                    --currentLetter;
                }
                else {
                    if (!left.empty()) {
                        std::u32string s = utf8ToUcs4(text.text);
                        s.insert(s.begin(), left.back());
                        left.pop_back();
                        right.insert(right.begin(), s.back());
                        s.pop_back();
                        text.setText(renderer, font, ucs4ToUtf8(s), {});
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (event.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT) {
                if (currentLetter != utf8ToUcs4(text.text).size()) {
                    ++currentLetter;
                }
                else {
                    if (!right.empty()) {
                        std::u32string s = utf8ToUcs4(text.text);
                        s.push_back(right.front());
                        right.erase(0, 1);
                        left.push_back(s.front());
                        s.erase(0, 1);
                        text.setText(renderer, font, ucs4ToUtf8(s), {});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (event.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT) {
            utf8Insert(text.text, currentLetter, event.text.text);
            text.setText(renderer, font, text.text, {});
            ++currentLetter;
            while (text.dstR.x + text.dstR.w > r.x + r.w) {
                --currentLetter;
                left.push_back(utf8ToUcs4(text.text)[0]);
                utf8Erase(text.text, 0);
                text.setText(renderer, font, text.text, {});
            }
        }
    }

    void draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer, TTF_Font* font)
    {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 0);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r);
        if (isPassword) {
            std::string currPassword = text.text;
            text.setText(renderer, font, std::string(utf8GetSize(currPassword), '*'), {});
            text.draw(renderer);
            text.setText(renderer, font, currPassword, {});
        }
        else {
            text.draw(renderer);
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 0);
        Text t = text;
        t.text = utf8Substr(t.text, 0, currentLetter);
        t.setText(renderer, font, t.text, {});
        if (currentLetter) {
            cursorR.x = t.dstR.x + t.dstR.w;
        }
        else {
            cursorR.x = t.dstR.x;
        }
        if (isSelected) {
            SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &cursorR);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    TTF_Init();
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("TextEditInput", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, windowWidth, windowHeight, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    TTF_Font* robotoF = TTF_OpenFont("res/roboto.ttf", 72);
    int w, h;
    SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &w, &h);
    SDL_RenderSetScale(renderer, w / (float)windowWidth, h / (float)windowHeight);
    bool running = true;
    Input input;
    input.r.w = 200;
    input.r.h = 30;
    input.r.x = windowWidth / 2 - input.r.w / 2;
    input.r.y = windowHeight / 2.f - input.r.h - 10;
    input.text.dstR.w = input.r.w;
    input.text.dstR.h = input.r.h;
    input.text.dstR.x = input.r.x;
    input.text.dstR.y = input.r.y;
    input.text.autoAdjustW = true;
    input.text.wMultiplier = 0.5;
    input.cursorR.w = 8;
    input.cursorR.h = input.r.h - 2;
    input.cursorR.x = input.r.x;
    input.cursorR.y = input.r.y + input.r.h / 2 - input.cursorR.h / 2;
    input.isSelected = true;
    while (running) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            input.handleEvent(event, robotoF);
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT || event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && event.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        input.draw(renderer, robotoF);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try a SDL-specific library like the nanogui-sdl mentioned [here](https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=11747&sid=7eaaca62720b54512ccecc4a9642dfc5)

Comment: Looks nice, but it's C++. The OP only tagged C. From this, they can only take the general idea to look for within-SDL toolkits.