# Combining SDL windows and GTK+ windows in the same program

Tags: c, gtk, sdl

I'm creating and SDL program in which some functions open GTK+ windows. The main window is an SDL window and the GTK+ windows are mostly dialog boxes. The `main()` function opens the SDL window normally and has a `while` loop with SDL events like usually in SDL. Some SDL events call functions that open GTK+ windows like GTK+ windows usually are opened and that have the same structure as the `main()` has in a GTK+ program.

All windows open as they should, the problem is about closing the GTK+ windows. When I close a GTK+ window, it stays opened until I close the main SDL window. The only thing that happens when I close the GTK+ window is that it doesn't do anything more after it's closed, so for example if I minimize it and then maximize it again, it becomes empty. When I close it, the SDL window also reacts to events as it should, like if the GTK+ window didn't exist. So everything is just as if the GTK+ window was closed except that it's still visible. I have a `g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window),"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);` line in each function that opens a GTK+ window, so that's not the problem.

How can I do so that the GTK+ window closes but not the SDL window when I click on the close button in the GTK+ window?

This is the structure of the code (the GTK window is an About dialog box here):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#ifdef WINDOWS
    #include <windows.h>
#endif

void openGtkWindow(){
    GtkWidget *aboutWindow = gtk_about_dialog_new();
    //Write things in the About window
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(aboutWindow),"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(aboutWindow);
    gtk_main();
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
    SDL_Surface *screen;
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    putenv("SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED=center");
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("SDL window",NULL);
    SDL_WM_SetIcon(IMG_Load("icon.png"),NULL);
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(600,400,32,SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    //Draw things in the SDL window
    SDL_Flip(screen);
    int continuer = 1;
    while(continuer){
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type){
            case SDL_QUIT:
                continuer = 0;
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT){
                    if(/*Test if the mouse is inside the About button*/){
                        openGtkWindow();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice to see you liked my suggestion of GTK+ in the other thread :) Are you handling all GTK+ events by manually running all necessary `gtk_main_iteration()`s as mame98 showed? If so, then (A) closing the `GtkWindow` should by default cause it to be fully destroyed, and (B) that callback to `gtk_main_quit()` can't do anything (useful) as you haven't first handed off control to any `gtk_main()` proper. The symptom you mentioned does sound like maybe GTK+ is not getting any/enough to itself to actually destroy, or at least redraw, the `GtkWindow` - so the window manager gets left with a 'ghost'.

Comment: Would be helpfull to see the whole code. Also, do you stay in the SAME loop after terminating the GTK window? maybe you stopp handeling events after calling `gtk_widget_destroy`?

Comment: Yeah, that'll avoid us having to speculate in the dark!

Comment: @mame98 I added the structure of my code.

Comment: As you are using a gtk Dialog, try gtk_dialog_run..

Comment: That code will not compile (`continue` cannot be used as an identifier). Also if SDL is initializing GTK+ itself, you can't run a second copy of GTK+ in another thread, especially if at some point you wind up, intentionally or not, mixing GTK+ 2 and GTK+ 3 in the same process. I'm not sure how SDL uses GTK+, I only know that it *can*. Oh, and if you're looking to run a miniature version of the GTK+ event loop like in the answer below in a separate thread, don't; only the thread that calls `gtk_init()` can use GTK+ directly. Any other thread must use `gdk_threads_add_idle()` and synchronize.

Comment: @andlabs I tried replacing `gtk_main` with the code in the answer below but then the window wouldn't close at all, and it wouldn't even let me use the SDL window any more. I would like to avoid opening the GTK+ window in the `main` function because I posted a simplified version of my code, so in fact, my code is much more complicated and the `openGtkWindow()` is called many times sometimes outside of the `main` function. And I can only use `gtk_init` in the `main` function because it uses `argc` and `argv`.

Comment: I don't use SDL so I don't know the answers to most of your questions, but I will say `gtk_init(NULL, NULL)` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Don't run `gtk_main()` within some function, as it's blocking and will take over execution of your program! And don't just replace it, literally where it is, with what mame98 suggested: implement a `while (pending) iteration();` event 'flush' in your custom main loop. When you say `I would like to avoid opening the GTk+ windows in the main function`, OK, you can prefer _writing_ the code that _flags_ them to be opened wherever you want, but at some point, you need to give GTK+ some time to actually _do_ what you've flagged it to do... without going too far and blocking the rest of your program

Comment: @andlabs I see no issues with threading here, so I think that's a red herring. GTK+ is initialised in `main()`, and `openGtkWindow()` is called from `main()` - all the same thread. There would only be a problem if trying to do anything with GTK+ widgets from another thread, e.g. in a callback if the other library happened to run that in another (been there... _done that_). The real problem is probably the fact that `openWindow()` invokes a blocking `gtk_main()` loop instead of returning and polling for events later, thus letting the rest of the program and the SDL main loop actually do things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to handle the GTK events in your while loop (I asume you do not call `gtk_main` and you stay in your custom `while` loop).

You can do this by using something similar to this:

```
while (running)
{
    while (gtk_events_pending()) // are there GTK events to handle
        gtk_main_iteration();    //   - If so, handle them

    // Your SDL Code
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the usual way to handle it. But if the OP's windows are showing at all, one would assume they're already giving GTK+'s main loop time to do things... right?

Comment: Perhaps they're doing a bunch of `iteration`s in order to make the window show up, but not handling any subsequent events, including `delete-event`. In which case, again, the pattern you've shown here is the solution. Otherwise, like you said, more code is needed.